# Can't find .Net 2.0 XML Schema

Tags: c#, xml, .net-2.0, app-config, xml-namespaces

I'm currently setting up an application config for a WPF application written in .Net 4.0. The connection string in the app.config is encrypted like so:

```
  <connectionStrings configProtectionProvider="DataProtectionConfigurationProvider">
    <EncryptedData>
      <CipherData>
        <CipherValue>CypherValue</CipherValue>
      </CipherData>
   </EncryptedData>
  </connectionStrings>
```

To use the EncryptedData element I need to include the XMLNS "http://schemas.microsoft.com/.NetConfiguration/v2.0". Attempting to include it produces an error as the schema cannot be found. Is there a way to include the schema or perhaps a different element I could use instead of EncryptedData?

Edit here's my entire app.config as it is:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>

<configuration xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/.NetConfiguration/v2.0">
<configSections>
    <section name="dataconfiguration" type="Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.Data.Configuration.DatabaseSettings, Microsoft.Practices.EnterPriseLibrary.Data, Version=3.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=aebf961ca224e888"/>
  </configSections>
  <dataconfiguration defaultDatabase="LoanersTest">
    <providerMappings>
      <add databaseType="Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.Data.Sql.Database, Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.Data, Version=3.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=aebf961ca224e888" name="System.Data.SqlClient" />      
    </providerMappings>
  </dataconfiguration>
  <appSettings>
    <add key="BufferSize" value="999999"/>
  </appSettings>
  <connectionStrings configProtectionProvider="DataProtectionConfigurationProvider">
    <EncryptedData>
      <CipherData>
        <CipherValue>
          CypherValue
        </CipherValue>
      </CipherData>
     </EncryptedData>
  </connectionStrings>
</configuration>
```

Edit: Added the xmlns as I attempted at first in the app.config.

Edit 2: Apologize for not including the error.

Error while trying to run project: Unable to start program 'C:...\Program.exe'. This application has failed to start because the application configuration is incorrect. Review the manifest file for possible errors. Reinstalling the application may fix this problem. For more details, please see the application event log.

Comment: What do you mean, attempting to include it? Show what you tried.

Comment: @JohnSaunders I've edited the main post to include the entirety of what I'm attempting to do.

Comment: Try putting that xmlns on the EncryptedData element itself, only.

Comment: Still can't find schemas. Tried putting it on the connectionStrings element as well as configProtectionProvider isn't an allowed attribute.

Comment: Exactly what error do you get? I don't believe that it is "looking for a schema"

Comment: @JohnSaunders Multiple errrors along the lines of "Could not find schema information for the element "Http://schemas.mcrosoft.com/.NetConfiguration2.0:connectionStrings'."

Comment: What makes you think that's an error?

Comment: @JohnSaunders Probably the fact that it fails to compile but compiles when I switch out that config for a working one with a connection string that isn't encrypted.

Comment: _what_ fails to compile??? You haven't shown us any error messages, and config files don't generally compile.

Comment: @JohnSaunders I apologize. I meant start moreover than compile. I'll include the error in my post.

Comment: Maybe you should start over. Show us the steps from an unencrypted connection string that works when you start the program, show us how  you encrypted the connection string, then show us the error you get. The _full_ error, please. If there are details in the application event log, then show us.

Answer (score 0):

Change your connection string like this, it will work!

```
 <connectionStrings configProtectionProvider="DataProtectionConfigurationProvider" configuration="" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/.NetConfiguration/v2.0">
        <EncryptedData>
          <CipherData>
            <CipherValue>sfdfdsfdfsdf</CipherValue>
          </CipherData>
        </EncryptedData>
      </connectionStrings>
    </configuration>
```